# Tic Tac Toe React Js : Not able to print location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tic-tac-toe

I am following Tic tac toe tutorial from https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

I want to print location of cell being clicked

[image]

My Code :

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      history: [
        {
          squares: Array(9).fill(null), location : 0 
          // Here I have introduced location to hold index
        }
      ],
      stepNumber: 0,
      xIsNext: true
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
    this.setState({
      history: history.concat([
        {
          squares: squares, location : i  // Assigning Index
        }
      ]),
      stepNumber: history.length,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext
    });
  }

  jumpTo(step) {
    this.setState({
      stepNumber: step,
      xIsNext: (step % 2) === 0
    });
  }

  render() {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);
    console.log("Hi : " + history[this.state.stepNumber].location + ", " + this.state.stepNumber) // Console logs print correct location value
    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
       var desc = move ?
        'Go to move #' + move :
        'Go to game start';
      desc = desc + " : " + history[this.state.stepNumber].location;
      return (
        <li key={move}>
          <button onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
        </li>
      );
    });

   // This display of Index is getting updated with each clicks

    let status;
    if (winner) {
      status = "Winner: " + winner;
    } else {
      status = "Next player: " + (this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
    }

    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board
            squares={current.squares}
            onClick={i => this.handleClick(i)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{status}</div>
          <ol>{moves}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById("root"));

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Output :

The location is getting updated with latest value in all list items like below screens :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to print Index

> Go To Move #X : [ Index of cell ]

Index is getting updated for each list item with latest value.

Note : All cells index starting from 0 to 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this

```
var desc = move ?
        'Go to move #' + move :
        'Go to game start';
desc = desc + " : " + history[this.state.stepNumber].location;
```

to

```
const desc = move ?
        `Go to move #' + move + ` : ` +  step.location` :
        'Go to game start';
```

Comment: It worked, can you explain me what was wrong in `history[this.state.stepNymber].location`

Comment: Removed '$' and corrected your answer which worked for me

Comment: because `history[this.state.stepNymber].location` is current location, that is why you have everywhere same value, current location.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe store the moves in an array.
And you can render it like so:

move is the index of cell

```
this.state.moves.map((move, i)=><p key={i}>Go to Move #X: {move}</p>)
```

Comment: This is not working, i tried. My state.moves is not array

Comment: You need to make it one